# How to fetch link from a file and loop it in python?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary, for-loop

have a txt  file with values

```
https://www.redbook.com.au/cars/details/2019-honda-civic-50-years-edition-auto-my19/SPOT-ITM-524208/
http://www.redbook.com.au/cars/research/used/details/1968-ford-fairmont-xt-manual/SPOT-ITM-336135
http://www.redbook.com.au/cars/research/used/details/1968-ford-f100-manual/SPOT-ITM-317784
```

code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.redbook.com.au/cars/details/2019-honda-civic-50-years-edition-auto-my19/SPOT-ITM-524208/'

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
page = (requests.get(url, headers=headers))


tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
car_data = {}

# Overview
if tree.xpath('//tr[td="Badge"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()'):
    badge = tree.xpath('//tr[td="Badge"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()')[0]
    car_data["badge"] = badge
if tree.xpath('//tr[td="Series"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()'):
    car_data["series"] = tree.xpath('//tr[td="Series"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()')[0]
if tree.xpath('//tr[td="Body"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()'):
    car_data["body_small"] = tree.xpath('//tr[td="Body"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()')[0]


df=pd.DataFrame([car_data])
```

output :

```
df=

              badge         body_small       series       
  0     50 Years Edition      Sedan         10th Gen
```

how to take all the `urls` from txt file and loop it so that the output will append all  values into a dict or df.

expected output

```
             badge         body_small        series 

  0     50 Years Edition      Sedan         10th Gen
  1     (No Badge)            Sedan           XT
  2     (No Badge)            Utility     (No Series)
```

tried converting the file into list and used forloop

```
url = ['https://www.redbook.com.au/cars/details/2019-honda-civic-50-years-edition-auto-my19/SPOT-ITM-524208/','http://www.redbook.com.au/cars/research/used/details/1966-ford-falcon-deluxe-xp-manual/SPOT-ITM-386381']
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
for lop in url:
    page = (requests.get(lop, headers=headers))
```

but only one url value is generating. and if there are 1000 url converting them to list will take a lot of time

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What do you mean by how to take? What's your expected output?

Comment: updated question pl check @balderman

Comment: updated question pl check @MohamedThasinah

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is you are overwriting the variable 'page' again and again in the for loop, hence you will get data of the last request only.
Below is the correct code

```
url = ['https://www.redbook.com.au/cars/details/2019-honda-civic-50-years-edition-auto-my19/SPOT-ITM-524208/','http://www.redbook.com.au/cars/research/used/details/1966-ford-falcon-deluxe-xp-manual/SPOT-ITM-386381']
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
page = []
for lop in url:
    page.append(requests.get(lop, headers=headers).text)
```

Comment: if i increase the urls for 1000 it would take more time to append right?

Comment: getting this error : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'content'

Comment: you got no attribute 'content' error because you may have tried to print page.content, but here page is a list of responses object so you have to try printing page[0].content for the content of first url, page[1].content for the second and so on. `page.append(requests.get(lop, headers=headers)) `, instead of storing array of response objects now we are storing the content itself as text, `page.append(requests.get(lop, headers=headers).text)` for the ease of use.

Comment: getting this error   str object has no attribute content

Comment: where u r getting that error? I was able to run the given code snippet without any errors.

Comment: where u r getting that error? I was able to run the given code snippet without any errors. page[0] will have the response as string for the first URL, page[1] will have the response as string for the second as so on. Basically each item in the page list is a String object. It will not have the attribute content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197266/discussion-between-thor-is-and-vishnu-ks).

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly then this is the answer for you question.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

cars = [] # gobal array for storing each car_data object


f = open("file.txt",'r') #file.txt would contain all the links that you wish to read

#This for loop will perform your thing for each url in the file
for url in f:    

      car_data={} # use it as a local variable

      headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
      page = (requests.get(url, headers=headers))


      tree = html.fromstring(page.content)


      # Overview
      if tree.xpath('//tr[td="Badge"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()'):
          badge = tree.xpath('//tr[td="Badge"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()')[0]
          car_data["badge"] = badge
      if tree.xpath('//tr[td="Series"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()'):
          car_data["series"] = tree.xpath('//tr[td="Series"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()')[0]
      if tree.xpath('//tr[td="Body"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()'):
          car_data["body_small"] = tree.xpath('//tr[td="Body"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()')[0]

      cars.append(car_data) #Append it to global array
```

Comment: still printing only one

Comment: make sure each url is a line in the file. I tried and it worked .. it reads line by line. for each url must be a new line.

Comment: car_data should append all the data. but it is not happening

Comment: put the car_data outside the loop. it was clearing the car_data={} for every iteration. now i corrected .. i never know you want to append the car data @thoris .. please approve the answer if it helped you.

Comment: car_data has no data

Comment: try doing one thing.... create an array outside the loop globally and then each iteration create a car_data dictionary and append the dictionary to the global array.... here the thing is that you are over writing the value in the same key that is badge, series and body_small..@thoris please see the answer now... cars array will have all your car_data dictionaries we created in each iteration. hope its clear ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197288/discussion-between-thor-is-and-paul-p-joby).

Answer (score 0):

Here (The code will generate a dictionary where each entry is the url (key) + the scraped data (value))

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_cars_data(url):
    cars_data = {}
    # TODO read the data using requests and with BS populate 'cars_data'
    return cars_data


all_cars = {}
with open('urls.txt') as f:
    urls = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    for url in urls:
        all_cars[url] = get_cars_data(url)

print('done')
```

Comment: where should i add the code? can you explain it more. its lil confusing

Comment: @thoris See my 'TODO' comment. There you should add the code that already works for you. (Reading the data from the URL and passing it to BeautifulSoup). Is it clear now?

Comment: your output is not the same as mine.  i have mentioned the format. your output is generating   `url : {data}, ...`  it is not the way i requested